# Get open and closed posts count group by date with 1 week interval?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get Posts count of closed and open posts grouped by date and with 1 week interval. what i'm getting right now is.

[image]

what i want is, like this.

[image]

sorry for poor explanation.
Thanks!

Comment: what's your query? And what's the start day of a week you are expecting? (`Sunday or Monday`) ?

Comment: start of the week is monday.

Comment: But I see your expected output doesn't consist of the date_start and date_end as the start and end date of the corresponding week.

Comment: i need to show data of last 2 months with 1 week interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT 
date_posts - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date_posts) DAY AS date_start,
date_posts + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(date_posts)) DAY AS date_start,
COUNT(*) totalPosts,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Close_count = 1 THEN 1 END) closeCount,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Open_count = 1 THEN 1 END) openCount
FROM your_table
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_posts,1);
```

**Note:**

`YEARWEEK(date)` function assumes the start date is `Sunday`.

`YEARWEEK(date,1)` function assumes the start date is `Monday`.

`WEEKDAY(date)` function returns the index of the date of the corresponding week assuming `Monday` as the start day of a week. It returns `0` for `Monday`, `1` for `Tuesday` ..... and `6` for `Sunday`.

**EDIT:**

For date range search:

```
SELECT 
date_posts - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date_posts) DAY AS date_start,
date_posts + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(date_posts)) DAY AS date_start,
COUNT(*) totalPosts,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Close_count = 1 THEN 1 END) closeCount,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Open_count = 1 THEN 1 END) openCount
FROM your_table
WHERE date_posts >= YOUR_START_DATE - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(YOUR_START_DATE) DAY
AND date_posts <= YOUR_END_DATE + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(YOUR_END_DATE)) DAY 
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_posts,1);
```

So, based on this if you want to grab the result of last 5 weeks including current week you need to run the following query:

```
SELECT 
date_posts - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date_posts) DAY AS date_start,
date_posts + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(date_posts)) DAY AS date_start,
COUNT(*) totalPosts,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Close_count = 1 THEN 1 END) closeCount,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Open_count = 1 THEN 1 END) openCount
FROM your_table
WHERE date_posts >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 WEEK) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 WEEK) DAY
AND date_posts <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY 
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_posts,1);
```

Comment: Awesome Man, Thanks

Comment: i've got a little problem. i'm unable to include the current date. like i need to get all the records till current date

Comment: the above query gets all the records from your table (including current date).

Comment: it does not work. still same result :(. i did this. WHERE i.time_added >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 WEEK) - 
                 INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 WEEK)) DAY 
                 AND i.time_added <= NOW() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY 
                  GROUP BY YEARWEEK(i.time_added,1)

Comment: share your full query here

Comment: still same. i've added my whole query. please check

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(i.time_added - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(i.time_added)DAY)  AS date_start,
             DATE(i.time_added + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(i.time_added))DAY ) AS date_end,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT i.lead_id) AS Leads_count,
                         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.`stage` IN
                         ('6','8') THEN i.`lead_id`
                         ELSE NULL END) AS Close_count
                        ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.`stage` IN ('1','2','3','4','5','7','9')
                         THEN i.`lead_id` ELSE NULL END) AS Open_count
                FROM tbl i
                INNER JOIN tbl s ON i.stage = s.status_id
                    INNER JOIN tbl u ON i.assigned_to = u.userid
                    INNER JOIN tbl p ON p.purpose_id = i.purpose
                 WHERE 1=1 AND i.STATUS = 'on' AND i.time_added >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 WEEK) - 
    INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 WEEK)) DAY 
                 AND i.time_added <= NOW() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY 
                  GROUP BY YEARWEEK(i.time_added,1)
```

Comment: why are those table instances (`s,u,p`)? And what's the result are you getting by running this query? What did you mean by **the results are same**?

Comment: i'm using joins, those are aliases. i edited table names. i need to get record till current day. i'm not getting that. i'm getting results till 26-jun-2016.

Comment: Ensure you have data after `26-jun-2016`

Comment: No, i don't have. but it does not matter. it should show date

Comment: Sorry to say brother you are misguided by yourself may be. Since you don't have data how on earth `MySQL` would show those missing data for you? By the way, the query is working fine. If you need to populate missing week's data then I would suggest to do this in application level.